# how do i write a method that switches the order of values in a pairwise

Tags: java

I have to write a method that accepts an array of strings as a parameter and switches the order of values in a pairwise fashion.

I have used a "For" loop, and add one more variable, instead of using "i+1" so i wont go out of bounds. The code doesn't work for all the cases.
please help me to understand what is wrong :)

```
 public static void swapPairs (String [] txt1){
     for(int i=0; i<txt1.length-1; i++){
            int j=1;
            String word=txt1[j];
            txt1[j]=txt1[i];
            txt1[i]=word;
            j++;
        }
    }





>test #1:{"four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"}
    >>what should i get {"score", "four", "seven", "and", "ago", "years"}
    >>>what i get:{"score", "years", "four", "and", "seven", "ago"}
```

Comment: If you want your iteration to work on pairs, you want your index incremented by 2 each turn.

Comment: *facepalm*
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this systematically by thinking of the different cases of input that you may receive. Some trivial cases would be:

- Case 1: an empty array of strings: `[]`
- Case 2: an array with a single string: `["a"]`
- Case 3: an array with a two strings: `["a", "b"]`

Some slightly more complicated examples could be:

- Case 4: an array with an odd number of strings: `["a", "b", "c"]`
- Case 5: an array with an even number of strings: `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

Now you could say that two of the trivial cases already cover the odd and even case, but I decided to include it to show a more concrete example.

Let's go over our small list of examples and see what we expect to get after calling `swapPairs`.

- Case 1: Well we would expect to be returned an empty array since there is nothing to swap!
- Case 2: Since there is only a single element, then we would expect to get the same array of strings back because there is no other string to swap with.
- Case 3: There is a single pair of strings in this array so we expect this pair to be swapped. We should be returned `["b", "a"]`.
- Case 4: Now we have an odd number of strings in our array where we'll need to swap at least once. Without diving into the algorithm, we expect to be returned `["b", "a", "c"]` since that is the only swap possible and `"c"` has no other string to be swapped with.
- Case 5: For this case, we have an even number of strings in our array which informs us that string will have a corresponding string to swap with. We expect to be returned `["b", "a", "d", "c"]`.

Hopefully by this point of going through multiple examples and different cases, you're starting to get an idea of how the algorithm should look like.

Let's start with Case 5: `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. The respective indices for each element in the array is `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. We want to swap the string at index 0 with the string at index 1. Similarly, we want to swap the string at index 2 with the string at index 3. **If we were to do this in a loop, your index incrementer should actually be increase by 2 instead of 1 since we want to skip the element we swapped with.**

Now that was the case for if every single string in the array had a corresponding string to swap with (ie. even number of elements). We may run into the case where there is an odd number of elements which means that the last element won't be swapped. You may want to perform a check to see if the element exists before actually doing a swap since indexing an array incorrectly will give you an `IndexOutOfBounds Exception`.

I'll leave it up to you to finish the code and hopefully this gives you more insight as to how you would want to approach problems.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to jump by 2:

```
public static void swapPairs (String [] txt1){
     for(int i=0; i<txt1.length-1; i=i+2){          
            String word=txt1[i+1];
            txt1[i+1]=txt1[i];
            txt1[i]=word;              
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your iteration to work on pairs, you want your index incremented by 2 each turn. Then you want to swap entries `i` and `i+1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < txt1.length - 1; i += 2) {
    String word = txt1[i+1];
    txt1[i+1] = txt1[i];
    txt1[i] = word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the in-place algorithm with no check for edge cases:

```
public static void swapPairs(String[] txt1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < txt1.length; i += 2) {
        String temp = txt1[i - 1];
        txt1[i - 1] = txt1[i];
        txt1[i] = temp;
    }
}
```